# How i can use static factory method in my code in java

Tags: java, collections

```
List<VO> list = new ArrayList<VO>();
```

I have another list of type `object[]` which contains nearly 100 items.Then i need to 
   iterate and put those values into `vo`.So i write the following code.

```
for(Object[] obj:list1){
  VO vo = new VO();

   vo.setName(obj[0].toString);
    .....
}
```

Here i am creating 100 objects.But i heard creating too much objects will decrease the
   performance.Is there any way to reduce no of objects here.Thanks in advance...

Comment: Either store the objects or create them on demand, there's a performance penalty on storage or cpu. No way around that.

Comment: why downvote.Please give me a reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, based off the given information, there is no way to do that without creating one `V0` object for each `Object` in `list1`.

However, Java shouldn't slow down doing this. 100 objects is really a rather inexpensive operation.

As an aside: I suggest using better names for your variables. Yours are confusing and needlessly short.

Comment: actually i mean not 100 objects.I have thse type code in several places in my project

Answer (score 1):

If your `list` has to have 100 references to different `VO` objects in the end, then there's no way you can avoid creating them, pretty much by definition.

While creating too many objects *can* indeed create performance problems, you probably shouldn't worry about that at the moment. Creating 100 objects it *incredibly* cheap in general. You should focus on writing clear code, and then *measuring* performance - only start trying to think of complex ways of improving performance after you've got something which *works*, but not fast enough.

Comment: actually i mean not 100 objects.I have thse type code in several places in my project

Comment: is there any limit for jvm on maximum no of objects

Comment: @PSR: Well objects are garbage collected - but obviously there's a limit for how many can be retained at the same time, based on your memory. But again, how could you possibly expect to have a list with 100 objects in without creating 100 objects? It's really not clear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to the original object in `list1` wnd keep `list1` available, something like this:

```
for(Object[] obj:list1){
  list.add((VO)obj);
}
```

Or:

```
List<VO> list = new ArrayList<VO>(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the real type of the formal type Object? Certainly, the real type is not object, then toString would print out just the ObjectID. I cannot believe that this is what you want.

So, what is the real type? Wouldn't be a type cast to the VO object enough?

List list = (new ArrayList()).addAll(list1);

Assuming that list1 contains only VO objects.